# Is there any circumstance in which the DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout can be exceeded when executing Open() method?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-server

I was monitoring my web application (hosted on azure with db azuresql) I found that, occasionally, there is a failure to establish the connection to the database, and the Open() method can take up to 40 seconds to fail (with a timeout exception). It turns out that in the connection string I have defined a "Connection Timeout" of 5 seconds.

Is there any circumstance in which the DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout can be exceeded when executing Open() method?

Comment: Are you asking why it takes 40 seconds to timeout even though you've specified 5 seconds in the connection string?

Comment: yes @Xerillio, any idea?